# In jVectorMap, how to select a region ONLY IF a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm using jVectorMaps. By default, it does not allow selecting regions UNLESS                 >>`regionsSelected: true`

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

When a user clicks on a region he/she gets prompted a question taken from the loaded JSON file. I need the region color to change **ONLY** in case the answer to the question is correct.

My code so far:

```
$(function(){
  map = new jvm.Map({
    container: $('#map'),
    map: 'world_mill_en',//map file
    backgroundColor: ['#1E90FF'],//map background color    
    regionsSelectable:true,//this needs to be true to be able to select a region

    onRegionClick: function(event, code){
      var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
      var regionName = map.getRegionName(code);
      $.getJSON('../countries.json', function(data) {
        for (var i in data.country) {
          if (data.country[i].name === regionName){
            var answer = prompt(data.country[i].question, "Type your answer here.");
            if(data.country[i].answer === answer){
              alert("Correct!");
            }else{
              alert("Wrong. Try again.");
            }
          }
        }
      });
    },

  });
});
```

I think I have to find a way to dynamically change the property value of `regionsSelectable` after the `if(data.country[i].answer === answer)` condition is met. If it is not then the property value of `regionsSelectable` should remain `false`.

I'm a beginner so any criticism is more than welcome, I'm probably way off mark here anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out ..

```
 $(function(){
          map = new jvm.Map({
            container: $('#map'),
            map: 'world_mill_en',//map file
            backgroundColor: ['#1E90FF'],//map background color    
            regionsSelectable:true,//this needs to be true to be able to select a region

            onRegionClick: function(event, code){
              var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
              var regionName = map.getRegionName(code);
              $.getJSON('../countries.json', function(data) {
                for (var i in data.country) {
                  if (data.country[i].name === regionName){
                    var answer = prompt(data.country[i].question, "Type your answer here.");
                    if(data.country[i].answer === answer){
                      map.setSelectedRegions(code);;
                    }else{
                     map.clearSelectedRegions();

                    }
                  }
                }
              });
            },

          });
        });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! It almost works now. I'm able to select the country based on the condition. 

But say if I have 5 countries selected (that's 5 correct answers in a row), and I answer one wrong all the selected countries get deselected. I need only that one country to be deselected. Let me know if you have any thoughts on that. Thanks again

Comment: Try method map.getSelectedRegion()  to get the currently selected regions before each region click

Comment: thanks, I'll mark this as an answer as it got me on the right track